# How to navigate programmatically react-router-dom v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I came back to react world after a few years. And things certainly have changed for good. I'm using `MemoryRouter` for my app. And I can navigate fine by using `Link`. But `useNaviate` hook is not working as expected. It does nothing on the page. Could you please help me here? Here is my code:

Router:

```js
<MemoryRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
  </Routes>
</MemoryRouter>
```

Here is how I'm trying the navigation:

```js
function Home() {
  // demo purpose
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  
  navigate('/dashboard')
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm using it right, or if I need to do something else here.

Comment: Errors in thee console?

Comment: NVM. Found the issue. navigate should either be an event, or should be in useEffect.

Answer (score 1):

The code is calling `navigate` as an unintentional side-effect directly in the  function component body.

Either call `navigate` from a component lifecycle or callback to issue an imperative navigation action:

```
function Home() {
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (/* some condition */) {
      navigate('/dashboard');
    }
  }, [/* dependencies? /*]);
  
  ...
}
```

Or conditionally render the [`Navigate`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/navigate) component to a declarative navigation action:

```
function Home() {
  ...

  if (/* some condition */) {
    return <Navigate to="/dashboard" />;
  };
  
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was calling `navigate` directly when the component was rendering. It should either be called in an event, or it should be called in `useEffect` hook.

Answer (score 0):

Make your navigate in function call or in useEffect like this:

```
function Home() {
// demo purpose
const navigate = useNavigate()
  useEffect(() => {
    navigate('/dashboard')
  }, []);
}
```